# Не могу получить файл в java/srping-rest контроллере кидает ошибку

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, multipart

Не могу получить файл в java/srping-rest контроллере кидает ошибку, точнее файл получаю лежит он по пути [C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.3295759470297339579.8080\work\Tomcat\localhost\core] но кидает неизвестную и непонятную мне ошибку не могу разобраться уже неделю, помогите пж!

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity create(@PathVariable("filename") MultipartFile filename{
    long size = filename.getSize();
    System.out.println("=+++++++++++++++++++++>>>>>>FILE EXISTTT  " + size);
    return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
}
```

[image: Запрос отправляю с Postman]

Вот какую ошибку кидает:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/core] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException] with root cause
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile[0]->org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile["inputStream"]->java.io.FileInputStream["fd"])
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в методе, после описания входного параметра, нет закрывающей скобки.

Comment: нет она есть, просто когда код вставлял видимо удалил нечаянно

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно используете аннотацию @PathVariable. Это для получения параметров из адресной строки. Так можно передать имя файла, но не сам файл. 
Для файла используйте аннотацию @RequestParam.

Примерно так должно быть:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity uploadFile(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName,
 @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) {
///
}
```

Еще надо не забыть в конфигурации настроить компонент CommonsMultiPartResolver.